# Pattern is not working for Positive Integer number in Angular 4 form builder

Tags: regex, validation, angular2-forms, formbuilder, redux-form-validators

I am using Angular 4 and Reactive form (using form builder), I have one field in my form name Quantity of Products so we know that quantity does not contain Nagative value and floating value, please suggest me right pattern for that

```
<input type="number" formControlName="quantity" class="form-control">

 this.myForm = this._fb.group({
    quantity: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[+]?[1-9]\d*$/)]],
    });
```

**I don't want to allow user to enter nagative value, zero, dot(.) and any other syboles like - and e.**

**I want only positive + Integer (whole number)**

Thanks in advance
please help me

Comment: Your current pattern [`^[+]?[1-9]\d*$`](https://regex101.com/r/YvSg9p/1/) matches an optional `+` sign followed by a digit 1 - 9 and then zero or more times `\d` so you can not start with a zero. Is that not what you want to match?

Comment: we can enter multiple time dot (.) value in it, I don't want to allow any dots in it, it is also allow - minus sign but I don't want - minus sign too

make sure I am using input type="number" not text